# Как написать функцию в SQL, которая формирует новые цены для товаров?

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Мне нужно выполнить задание из вуза.
Задание: Напишите функцию, которая увеличивает стоимость товара на 5% от его предыдущей стоимости при каждой следующей покупке этого товара.

Скрипт базы (она была уже дана и править её нельзя):

```
CREATE DATABASE [test1]
GO

USE [test1]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Товар](
    [Код_товара] [int] PRIMARY KEY,
    [Тип_товара] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [Название] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Характеристики] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Стоимость] [int] NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Чек](
    [Номер_чека] [int] PRIMARY KEY,
    [Дата_оформления] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Время_выполнения] [time] NOT NULL,
    [Дата_оплаты] [datetime] NOT NULL,
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Содержимое_чека](
    [Номер_чека] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Код_товара] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Количество] [int] NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Номер_чека, Код_товара),
    FOREIGN KEY(Номер_чека) REFERENCES Чек(Номер_чека),
    FOREIGN KEY(Код_товара) REFERENCES Товар(Код_товара)
)
GO
```

У меня был такой вариант, но он просто все суммы чека увеличивает на 5%.

```
Create function f1()
returns @t table (Номер_чека int, Стоимость int)
as
begin
Insert @t 

    SELECT Чек.Номер_чека, SUM((Товар.Стоимость * dbo.Содержимое_чека.Количество)+(Товар.Стоимость * dbo.Содержимое_чека.Количество)/100*5) AS Стоимость_чека
    FROM dbo.Содержимое_чека
    INNER JOIN dbo.Товар ON dbo.Содержимое_чека.Номер_чека  = dbo.Товар.Код_товара
    INNER JOIN dbo.Чек ON dbo.Чек.Номер_чека = dbo.Содержимое_чека.Номер_чека 
    WHERE dbo.Содержимое_чека.Номер_чека  in
    (
        SELECT Чек.Номер_чека
        FROM Чек
    )
    group by Чек.Номер_чека

return
end
go

Select * from dbo.f1()
```

Comment: никогда не понимал, в чем прелесть называть таблицы и столбцы по русски. по существу я бы сказал, что вам нужен триггер на создание чека, который после вставки проапдейти таблицу товаров и умножит цену на 1.05. То есть функция получает на вход id чека и апдейтит товары из него.

Comment: Про русские названия уже к преподавателю вопрос.
Спасибо за совет про триггеры